# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string in user defined function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Working on a function that should return a date. But I'm getting this error and I'm not sure how to fix it

```
if (@flow_date = eomonth(@flow_date) or day(@flow_date) < day(@lMaturityDate)) begin
                    set @lMaturityDate = eomonth(@lMaturityDate);
                end

                else begin


                    if  month(@lMaturityDate) < 10 BEGIN
                        set @month=concat('0',month(@lMaturityDate));

                    end
                    else Begin
                        set @month=month(@lMaturityDate);

                    END

                    set @lMaturityDate =convert(date,concat(year(@lMaturityDate),'-',@month,'-',day(@flow_date)))
            end

        END
            return isnull(@lMaturityDate,null);

    END
```

Sample code that casues the error, Im just noticed it throws the error for months greatr than 10

```
declare @month varchar(40);
 declare @lMaturityDate date = '2019-11-31'
 declare @flow_date date = '2019-04-25'

if  month(@lMaturityDate) < 10 BEGIN
                    set @month=concat('0',month(@lMaturityDate));

                end
                else Begin
                    set @month=month(@lMaturityDate);

                END
set @lMaturityDate  =convert(date,concat(year(@lMaturityDate),'-',@month,'-',day(@flow_date)))
select  @lMaturityDate
```

Comment: What does `concat(year(@lMaturityDate),'-',@month,'-',day(@flow_date))` read if you print it out?

Comment: Show us some sample data which causes the error,

Comment: I getting the error for months greater than 10

Comment: @DaleBurrell please see edited post

Comment: November only has 30 days...

Comment: noted but when I calling the function in a select statement the same error is reappearing

Comment: I found the same as @stickybit. Think the problem is that you are assuming the day() of one date works in the month() of another. Clearly it doesn't always for anything potentially greater than 28.

Answer (score 2):

The function is broken in that it assumes that whatever the day() of the flowdate is also works for the month of maturitydate. Clearly that is not the case for any day (potentially) after 28.

For example if Flowdate='2019-06-30' and Maturitydate='2019-02-28' then your result is date '2019-02-30' which is invalid.

You need to work out your logic for how to handle this. I would suggest looking for any date where the month of date+days > month of 1st of the month. If so then use the last day of the month.

That's just a suggestion, you may have other rules.

Comment: Much approached. If you are familiar with Oracle add_months function. Im trying to do the same in sql server. Any code simple would be welcomed

Comment: `select DATEADD(m,1,'2019-10-31')` which incidentally results in the 30th of November.

Comment: @TomC Yes it works in one direction, but not the other. Add one month to Nov 30 and what do you get? Not Dec 31 - which I think is OP's goal. And let's not forget February (which is more complicated).

Comment: Agree @SMor. One of those things that needs a decision from the business. I tend to think "last of the month" should be last of any month, regardless of number of days. I'm sure that the way my credit cards do it!